# How to integrate wso2 esb and wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We are using wso2 identity server as an IAM solution(for creating roles and users and tenants). We are now implementing the architecture using wso2 ESB (in wso2 integration studio). So is there a way where we can call the wso2 IS(Identity Server) API's from ESB?
Also, we were using script mediator in wso2 esb. Is there a way to generate authentication string here from the req body sent to the api being called.

I want to create this json using script mediator. is it possible because it is giving error?
json:

```
            {
                "schemas": [],
                "userName": requestbody.userName,
                "password": requestbody.password,
                "emails":
                    [

                        {
                            "primary": true,
                            "value": requestbody.userName
                        }
                    ],
                "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":
                {
                    "verifyEmail": true,
                    "oneTimePassword": requestbody.password
                }
            }
```

I have username and password coming in the body. I have to create rest of the fields using these two. Is it possible in script mediator?
I am trying to hit this endpoint from ESB '/scim2/Users', which is a wso2 identity server api and needs data in the above described format itself.
Please suggest a solution to implement this in wso2 ESB .

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a piece of advice. Do not use the script mediator unless you absolutely have to. Building a json message is easy enough with the PayloadFactory or even xslt.

Comment: Okay noted. But can you please suggest how we can add extra elements to the json object which are not coming from the request body using payload factory. Didn't find relevant documentations for our problem. Also we have to perform some processing on the elements coming from json body and then append it to our request. Is this also possible with payloadfactory. And Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: In that case can you elaborate in the question specifically on what you are trying to do?